# Get Video Views in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am really struggling to get the Facebook video views for each post on a public page (that I don't manage).

I have started with the Page ID object while collecting all posts:

```
pageid/posts?fields=message,created_time,permalink_url,comments.limit(0).summary(1),likes.limit(0).summary(1),shares,reactions.limit(0).summary(1)
```

but I can't find anything that will give me video views. I am able to get total count of shares, likes, reactions and comments but can't find a way to get video views.

I think it's a bit stupid, anyway I have also tried to looks specifically for videos, something like this:

```
pageid/videos?fields=video_insights
```

But among my video_insights fields there is nothing, no insights, no video views! I read that I just need a token with the read insights permissions (which I do) but it's not working. It only returns video IDs.

I have also typed the video view parameter myself in the code, but the result is still nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

happened to work on this last month

haven't found any available graph api

parse the view count from facebook video page finally

waiting graph api to move this metric to public api